# Rendering detailView in bootstrap-table is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table, detailsview

I'm attempting to display the **detailView** feature using the bootstrap-table library through a JavaScript script, but I'm having difficulty understanding why it's not functioning as expected. I've provided a simplified example below for reference. Despite the data and table being presented correctly, the detailView feature isn't operating properly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bootstrap Table CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.22.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">

  <title>Dummy</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Table -->
    <table id="table"></table>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Table JS -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.22.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    function renderTable(data, tableId) {
      const $table = $(`#${tableId}`);

      // Initialize the table
      const options = {
        columns: [{
            field: "id",
            title: "ID",
          },
          {
            field: "name",
            title: "Name",
          },
        ],
        data: data,
        detailView: true,
        detailFormatter: function(index, row) {
          return `<p>Details for ${row.name}</p>`;
        },
      };

      $table.bootstrapTable(options);
    }

    const data = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Item 1",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Item 2",
      },
    ];

    renderTable(data, "table");
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, can you add `<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css'>` this and check if it works . This will show you add icon and clicking on it you will see the detailView.

Comment: This fixed it. It seems bootstrap table requires the icons library as well.